# Rails in rendering unnecessary information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using RoR along with Bootstrap and I am trying to render my code into a snippet I found it online.
Basically I have this in my index:

```
 <%= @companies.each do |f| %>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <div class="row">
                   ...
                       <p><%= f.name %></p>                       
                       <p><%= f.description %></p>
                        ...        
                </div>
 <% end %>
             </div>
          </div>
```

However, it is rendering the bulk information about each item that was supposed to be render in this format:

`[#<Company id: 30, name: nil, description: nil, .....,  locations: nil, user_id: 3, chosenindustry_id: nil>]`

If someone could give me any hints at all that'd be great. At least tell me a little about what format this rendered code, that'd be amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
 <%= @companies.each do |f| %>
```

just delete =

```
 <% @companies.each do |f| %>
```

Comment: As always, equality changes everything.

Comment: @Gab_pt Remember the `=` in ERB indicates that the line will be echoed to the page. Things like `if` statements, `.each` loops, etc, should not be echoed (for the reason you're seeing).